# How to do a loop in SPSS with 3 variables?

Tags: loops, spss

I'm currently working on SPSS and I'm trying to create a loop.

First, each line of my data base corresponds to a month. Each individual (ID) has about 36 months (+/- 10).

As you can see in the picture, I created a variable that tells me the month of the individual's arrest (A1). The individual ID=1 was arrested in the 5th month (A1=5) and the individual ID=98 was arrested in the 3rd month (A1=3).

I would like to create a variable to find out how much money the individual made up to the month of arrest (CASH2). After that, I want the values in the rest of the column to be NA until the next ID. My problem is that the loop needs to include the ID (to make sure it's the same person), A1 (until it's not NA) and CASH. I have no idea how to do this :( Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Nice first question! Welcome to Stack-Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually require any loop. In the following syntax I first put the arrest month value in all the rows of each ID, and then by comparing the arrest month to the month of each row, I can tell SPSS where to copy the cash amount to cash2 and where not to:

```
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables overwrite=yes /break=ID /A1=max(A1).
if months<=A1 cash2=cash.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It help a lot! I didn't think of aggregate. I tried your synthax and the only thing I adjusted is : aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables overwrite=yes /break=ID_part /cashtot=max(cashtot). if (mois<=mois_arrest1) cashtot1=CASHTOT. Now it work!